# timestamp to milliseconds conversion around midnight getting messed up

Tags: perl

I am using following function to convert timestamp in format (e.g.) 02:49:02.506 to milliseconds in perl.

```
sub to_millis {
    my( $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $millis) = split /:/, $_[0];

    $millis += 1000 * $seconds;
    $millis += 1000 * 60 * $minutes;
    $millis += 1000 * 60 * 60 * $hours;

    return $millis;
}
```

I am then using the milliseconds generated from above routine to calculate the time difference between two timestamps in milliseconds. This works fine all day but gets messed up around midnight, when the timestamp changes to 00:00:00.000. So any logs generated for 1 hr (between 12am to 1am) gets me values in negative for the timestamp difference. Since my timestamp doesn't have a date in it, how do I fix this problem? I am trying to do this on a mobile device, which doesn't have many perl modules installed. So I don't have the liberty of using all the perl modules available.

Comment: If you know that these timestamps are always ordered, just add 24 hours to any negative value. `$time += to_millis(24) if $time < 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your timestamps will never be more than 23 hours 59 minutes apart?

Let's take two time stamps `A` and `B`. I am assuming that `A` happens before `B`.

Normally, if `A` is less than `B`, I know I can get my time by subtracting `A` from `B`. However, in this case, `A` is bigger than `B`. I now have to assume that I've wrapped around midnight. What do I do?

I know that the difference between `A` and `B` is `A` going to midnight, *PLUS* B.

For example, A is `11:58:30` and B is `00:02:00`

I know that A will be 90 seconds before midnight, and B will add another 120 seconds to that time. Thus, the total difference will be 90 + 120 = 210 seconds.

Using your routine:

```
my $midnight = to_millis( "23:59:00:000" );  # Need the time at midnight
my $a_time   = to_millis( $a_timestamp   );
my $b_time   = to_millis( $b_timestamp   );
my $time_diff;

if ( $a_time < $b_time ) {  # Normal timestamp issue
   $time_diff = $b_time - $a_time;
}
else {                      # We wrapped around midnight!
    my $first_part = $midnight - $a_time;   # Time from A to midnight
    $time_diff = $first_part + $b_time      # We add the time from midnite to B
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the ordering of your two timestamps, and if you know that they're no more than 24 hours apart, if you get a negative difference add 24 hours (86,400,000 milliseconds).

If you don't have that information, then you won't be able to distinguish between a 2-minute span and a span of 24 hours and 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You have two timestamps, A and B.  If B is always conceptually "after" A but the interval from A to B could cross a date boundary, then do

```
if (B < A) B+=86400000
```

and then do the subtraction.  Or equivalently

```
diff = B - A
if (diff < 0) diff+=86400000
```

If, however you are not guaranteed that B will always be "after" A, you have to decide what is the acceptable range of positive and negative values for the difference.  If it's more than half a day you're out of luck, there's no way to solve the problem as you cannot tell if a negative interval represents a real negative interval or a positive one that happened to cross a day boundary.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the wrap around at midnight:

```
$elapsed_ms = $t2_ms - $t1_ms;
if ($elapsed_ms < 0) $elapsed_ms += (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```